# Mobile Jquery full width

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a web page using mobile jquery, but it will not fit full width of mobile screen, if I implement the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;
minimum-scale=1.0; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

there is a header and content area with fixed widths, but as soon as I implement this tag it messes the form up. http://www.b-ar.co.za/leg/forms/register.html

Please I need help so urgently

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ',' instead of ';' and try setting this

```
width=device-width
```

to this

```
width=(your page width or your #wrapper width)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

change meta name viewport to

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>`